# Mystery - IE8 losing all cookies randomly for a few users

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8, cookies

Our site, which has a few hundred thousand users log in each day, is experiencing a very rare problem where certain IE8 users abruptly lose all their cookies, and therefore are then logged out. Typically a session for them goes like this:

1. they log in
2. they browse anywhere from 1-10 pages
3. their cookies disappear and 
   they're logged out
4. possibly repeat this process
5. eventually confused, they send us a feedback message 
   describing their troubles.

I noticed this question:

[Internet Explorer 8 Loses Cookies](https://superuser.com/questions/91781/internet-explorer-8-loses-cookies)

about IE8 cookie loss, although the original poster just had a bad date/time on their machine.  (This is not the case with our users.)   Interestingly, though, a few of the comments on that thread described the problem a few of our users are having.

Has anyone else heard of this or have a solution?

Some other notes:

- this only happens to IE8 users, and (possibly a false alarm?)
  every once in a great while an IE7 user.
  Those who get
  the problem are a small minority of IE8 users, but they get it repeatedly, over
  many days. So it seems to apply only
  to certain machines.
- there is no reliable user-agent
  pattern to this that we can find.
- it seems to be independent of OS
  version
- many users claim not to have any kind of internet security packages installed (although it's feasible they're confused about this)

Seriously - I appreciate any ideas out there! This mystery has been bugging us for months.